# What are the corresponding commands in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

This link: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BuildingOpenVPN-GUI provides the following instructions:

```
$ autoreconf -v
$ ./configure --with-crypto-includes=/c/openssl/include --with-crypto-lib=/c/openssl/lib
$ make
```

As I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, I would appreciate it if someone could show me the corresponding "sudo" commands. I understand that in Ubuntu, there's no such thing as a C:\ drive.

Thanks in advance.

----update----
Thank you guys for your help and suggestions. I know now that I don't need to sudo to issue the above commands.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain to me what the "c" in "/c/openssl/include" and "/c/openssl/lib" stand for? Does "c" in those statements stand for the C: drive or C compiler?

Comment: Are you aware you're building a Windows application (cross-compiling) in these steps using the MinGW compiler?

Comment: Yes sir. That's what I'm learning how to cross-compile for the MS Windows platform using Ubuntu. In the process I hope to learn how to use Ubuntu more productively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instructions can be used on Ubuntu (which, like the MinGW environment on Windows, uses bash as its shell) but you will have to change the paths to the include and lib directories. You execute them (*without* sudo) in a Terminal window after you have downloaded the source code, etc.

Comment: Exactly. No need to be root for compiling applications. It's a myth! :)

Comment: Could someone explain to me what the "c" in "/c/openssl/include" and "/c/openssl/lib" stand for? Does "c" in those statements stand for the C: drive or C compiler?

Comment: The commands are meant to be run (in bash) in a MinGW environment on Windows. When you do `ls /c` in such an environment you get the same as what you get when you do `ls C:`.

Comment: @ jdthood: Thanks for your pointers. Could you explain to me what is "ls" (without quotes)? I'm sorry if the question appears noobish to you. Well I did state right in my original post that I'm new.

Comment: @n00b Try `man ls` in a terminal to see the manual page about the `ls` command. It should more than answer your (new unrelated) question.

Answer (score 2):

Some commands in Ubuntu/Linux are not intended to be used by normal users (only administrators)

When this is necessary simply prefix the command with sudo for a detailed explanation see here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

However, the commands you have should not need sudo and will run without it.